# Flask Admin: TextArea with monospace font

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a database table with a column of type 'Text'. Flask-Admin displays this text in a TextArea field and allows me to edit it. However, I would like the text to display in *monospace font*. How can I do this?

I know that I can influence the widgets created by Flask-Admin by creating view classes. E.g. to increase the height of the text area I do:

```
class MyView(sqla.ModelView):
    form_widget_args = {'description' : {'rows' : 100}}
```

(where 'description' is the name of my text column). Is there an equivalent to the 'rows' keyword that lets me switch to monospace font? I couldn't find a comprehensive list of allowed keywords.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "allowed keywords" of the widget arguments dictionary are simply the various [HTML attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) that can be specified for the input field. That being said, attributes like `style` (shown below) are valid attributes for *all* HTML tags.

You should be able to accomplish what you want by specifying the `style` of the form widget to use a monospace font.

```
form_widget_args = {
    'description': {
        'rows': 100,
        'style': 'font-family: monospace;'
    }
}
```

Within the `style` field, you can specify *any* valid CSS that you would like to apply to the widget just like you would in standard HTML. The HTML equivalent here would be:

```
<textarea rows="100" style="font-family: monospace;"></textarea>
```

If you really want to be comprehensive in specifying a font family, you *could* do the following which would search for all the listed fonts prior to defaulting to the system monospace font.

```
form_widget_args = {
    'description': {
        'rows': 100,
        'style': 'font-family:Consolas,Monaco,Lucida Console,Liberation Mono,DejaVu Sans Mono,Bitstream Vera Sans Mono,Courier New, monospace;'
    }
}
```